# what's the best tool to look up C/C++ source code in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: java, android, c++, c, ubuntu

As we know , the SourceInsight is convenient to look up C/C++ source code on windows.

The eclipse is a good  choice for java code .

But what's the best tool to look up C/C++ source code in Ubuntu Linux ?

Comment: If you just intend to read the source code, wouldn't a simple text editor be enough ?

Comment: @ereOn 

I think the simple text editor is inconvenient and inefficient.

Comment: if you want to see the function definition in Eclipse CDT, just click on it and hit F3 and it will open the right file in the right place.

Comment: @ereOn I want to reopen the question .Please help me. Thanks. I had edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're comfortable with Eclipse, you can use that just fine in any linux distro as well. You may also want to have a look at [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) and [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), two command line tools that can be integrated into most editors and IDE's you may choose to use. They can of course be used standalone as well.

Comment: +1 to `ctags`/`cscope`, it brings not a very polished experience, but quite sufficient to browse even such a large codebase.

Answer (score 5):

If you want browse source code in easy and convenient way maybe you should generate code documentation with [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).
It generates html (or other format if you want) with source browser even without proper comments inside.

Answer (score 3):

You should try QT Creator, here is the link : http://qt.digia.com/Product/

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse has a plugin for C++ development called Eclipse CDT. Works fine on Windows and Linux